# Passing default arguments value in function not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, arguments

First of all, sorry for my lack of knowledge in PHP. I have tried googling for the answer, and also tried several answers here. For some reason passing argument in my function isn't working. However, if I directly call the default value in function, it works. Here is the function I am using.

```
function pnet_breadcrumbs( $seperator = '&raquo;', $home = true, $blog = true, $show_hierarchy = true ) {
    global $post, $wp_query;

    $html = '<div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="http://schema.org/">';
    $position = 1;
    if ( $home ) {
        $html .= '<span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="Go to ' . get_option( 'blogname' ) . '." href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" class="home"><span property="name">' . get_option( 'blogname' ) . '</span></a><meta property="position" content="' . $position . '"></span>' . $seperator;
        $html .= '  ' . $seperator . '  '; //Not Working
        $html .= '  &raquo;  '; //Working
        $position = $position + 1;
    }
    if ( is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ) {
        $obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        if ( $show_hierarchy ) {
            $ancestors = get_ancestors( $obj->term_id, $obj->taxonomy, 'taxonomy' );
            if ( is_array($ancestors) && !empty($ancestors) ) {
                $ancestors = array_reverse( $ancestors );
                foreach( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
                    $term_obj = get_term($ancestor);
                    $term_url = get_term_link($term_obj->term_id);
                    $html .= '<span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View Archive for %s.', 'pnet' ), $term_obj->name ) . '." href="' . $term_url . '" class="home"><span property="name">' . $term_obj->name . '</span></a><meta property="position" content="' . $position . '"></span>';
                    $html .= $seperator;
                    $position++;
                }
            }
        }

        $html .= '<span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><span property="name">' . $obj->name . '</span><meta property="position" content="' . $position . '"></span>';

    }
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $html .= '<span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><span property="name">' . sprintf( __( 'Search results for %s.', 'pnet' ), get_search_query() ) . '</span><meta property="position" content="' . $position . '"></span>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';

    echo $html;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'pnet_breadcrumbs', 0 );
```

The variable `$seperator` is returning empty.

I know this is basic PHP, but I really can't figure out why I can't use a default value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: @NigelRen `wpse_echo_char()`

Comment: I cannot replicate, works for me. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e0f56b072bc10f1572f919449917e843e0a9d08

Comment: It worked for me when using the PHP shell
`php > function wpse_echo_char( $sep = '&raquo;' ) {
php {
php {     echo $sep; //Doesn't work
php {     echo '&raquo;'; //Works
php {
php { }
php > wpse_echo_char();
&raquo;&raquo;
php > ` Maybe you're passing an empty variable?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have edited my question and provided the full function code that I am using.

Comment: Geez, why didn't you start with this? It completely changes the question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sorry sir, I though I should keep the question simple.

Comment: I don't have a WP environment in which I can test.

Comment: As the first line of your function enter `echo json_encode(func_get_args());return;` and see if and what varaiables are passed to the function when you call it